# Split html page into rows and cols

Tags: html, css

Hiw can I split my page into one top (50% height, width=100%) and two bottom columns(50% height, 50% width). 
I tried but no success...

```
    <html>
   <head>
   <title>CSS devide window into three (horizontal, 2 vertical )</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
.wrapM {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%x;
     padding:2px;
}
.wrapT {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;    
    padding:2px;
}
.wrapB {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;    
    padding:2px;
}
.wrapl {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;    
    padding:2px;
}

.wrapr {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;    
    padding:2px;
}



   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="wrapM">
    <div class="wrapT">Hello World This is upper Content</div>
       </div>
    <div class="wrapB">
    <div class="wrapl">Hello World This is bottom LEFT Content</div>
    <div class="wrapr">Hello World This is bottom right Content</div>
   </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `.wrapB1` and `.wrapB2` side by side, they should `float: left`. But this is not sufficient, because of the padding. Add `box-sizing: border-box` to have this fixed.

To get a height of 50%, `html` and `body` should be set to `100%` height. Additionally, you have a syntax error in your `height` specification of `.wrap`.

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/sgtb00nt/ to see a working version. I have also fixed the wrong nesting of `<div>`s.

Comment: @ Joachim Schirrmacher  I want to click in top part (.wrapT)..It should open any page , e.g., youtube in .wrapl . On double click in .wrapl or .wrapT, it should open an other page say google etc., in new widow.  Any idea?

Comment: Bind a `click` handler. But you should create another question for that.